# z3py examples do not to work on macOS

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I can not get any of the z3py examples to work. I was able to install it successful using the instructions from the README on github. I successfully updated my python path to point to the appropriate directory. Furthermore, I was able to successfully import z3, but I get an error every time I declare a variable. The compiler does not recognize Int, Ints, Real , RealVal.

I have included an example to illustrate.

Code:

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
solve(x > 2, y < 10, x + 2*y == 7)
```

> Error:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 3, in 
>       x = Int('x')
>   NameError: name 'Int' is not defined

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: What does `dir()` show you after `from z3 import *` ? Have you instead tried `import z3; x = z3.Int('x')` ?

Comment: @nekomantic: Thanks for your response. Here are the answers:

`from z3 import *
dir()
>>>['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> x = Int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Int' is not defined`

`>>> import z3
>>> x = Int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Int' is not defined`

Comment: After you `import` a module it should appear in the result of `dir()`, so I would check whether you've installed z3 properly.

Comment: @nekomantic I fixed that and the same problem persists even though it is seems to be importing properly. Here is the result. Thank you, again:
`>>> import z3
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', '__warningregistry__', 'z3']
>>> x = Int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Int' is not defined`

Comment: Please read my suggestion carefully: if you have done `import z3` then try `x = z3.Int('x')`, and so on.

Comment: Do you have `z3.py` in your working dir? It shadows installed package.

Comment: It finally works after a clean installation. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `z3-solver`: `pip install z3-solver`

There's a name conflict with `z3`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your local installation, either of Python or Z3.

I just compiled Z3 on my Mac and ran the example `test.py` you provided with no problems.  I'm using OS X 10.9.5 with Python 2.7.11 and the current master version of Z3 (commit 41edf5f).  The exact instructions I used were:

```
git clone https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git
cd z3
./configure
cd build
make -j4
emacs test.py
# Write in the example you gave.
python ./test.py
```

The output I got was `[y = 0, x = 7]`, which is the same output that I got from your script on my Linux box.  So the problem is specific to your OS X machine or build procedure.